# The free complete lattice on three generators, beyond ZF

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, universal-algebra, foundations, new-foundations

*This was originally [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4261226/28111); although it is still under bounty it seems unlikely to be answered there.*

[$\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that there is no free complete lattice on three generators](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1993166?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) since any such lattice would have to surject onto the ordinals. This isn't a problem in the context of set theories which admit a universal set, such as [$\mathsf{NFU}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#NewFounRelaSyst) or [$\mathsf{GPK}_\infty^+$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#SystGPKiOlivEsse). However, in such theories recursive constructions (which are utterly unproblematic in $\mathsf{ZF}$) become more complicated. So the status of the free complete lattice on three generators in such a theory is unclear to me:

> Is the existence of a free complete lattice on three generators consistent with either of $\mathsf{NFU}$ or $\mathsf{GPK_\infty^+}$?

Of course $\mathsf{NFU}$ and $\mathsf{GPK_\infty^+}$ are not the only two set theories with a universal set, and I'd be interested in an answer for any such theory. My focus on these two is due to $(i)$ my impression that $\mathsf{NFU}$ is the best-understood such set theory by far at the moment and $(ii)$ my personal liking of $\mathsf{GPK_\infty^+}$.

**EDIT**: I forgot to include exactly what "free complete lattice on three generators" means for me in this context (given that such notions are often more fragile in non-$\mathsf{ZF}$ contexts). While to a certain extent I'm interested in any reasonable interpretation of the phrase, I'm specifically interested in the following precisiation: a complete lattice $L$ with distinguished elements $a,b,c$ such that for every complete lattice $M$ and every $x,y,z\in M$ there is exactly one complete lattice homomorphism $L\rightarrow M$ sending $a$ to $x$, $b$ to $y$, and $c$ to $z$.

Comment: I think you can show that in $\mathsf{NFU}$ there is no complete lattice generated by three elements that satisfies the conditions in Crawley and Dean's definition 2. The issue I'm having with applying this to the definition of freeness in your MSE question is actually that it seems likely that not all lattices have completions in $\mathsf{NFU}$. The Dedekind-MacNeille completion of a lattice naturally lives one type higher than the lattice itself, which makes it seem like in general you only know that completions exist for lattices on Cantorian sets.

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, I don't see how to get Dedekind-MacNeille completions to work in such settings either. *(On that note I forgot to include my definition of freeness - fixed!)*

Comment: @JamesHanson In fact, I can't even show that "the free complete lattice on $V$ generators" doesn't exist! (That is, a pair $(X,f)$ where $X$ is a complete lattice and $f:\{x:x= x\}\rightarrow X$ is such that for every other complete lattice $A$ and every map $g:\{x:x =x\}\rightarrow A$ there is exactly one complete lattice homomorphism $h: X\rightarrow A$ such that $h\circ f=g$.)

Comment: Given the results in the Crawley-Dean paper, I suspect that if the free complete lattice with $3$ generators exists in a model of $\mathsf{NFU}$ with choice, then it would actually have the same with any number of generators, including $|V|$.